# Git package upgrade to latest using ansible

Tags: git, ansible

I am trying to upgrade git package to latest version on five of my `ubuntu-18.04` systems using `ansible playbook`. My ansible code as follows,

```yaml
    ---
    - hosts: gitservers
      tasks:
        - name: Update APT package manager repositories cache
          become: true
          apt:
            update_cache: yes
    
        - name: Install Git Package
          become: true
          apt:
            name: git
            state: latest
            update_cache: yes
```

**Last few lines of output:-**

```
TASK [Install Git Package] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [50.51.52.24]
ok: [50.51.52.23]
ok: [50.51.52.22]
ok: [50.51.52.25]
changed: [50.51.52.21]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************
50.51.52.21                : ok=3    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
50.51.52.22                : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
50.51.52.23                : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
50.51.52.24                : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
50.51.52.25                : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

It has upgraded git package only on `50.51.52.21` and i can see below given latest version.

```
# git --version
git version 2.31.1
```

However for remaining systems still have older version of git `( 2.17.1)`. I am not sure what is wrong in this. Can someone provide me pointers to solve this issue?

Manually on `50.51.52.22`system with below commands have upgraded successfully to `git version 2.31.1`

```
add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
apt-get update
apt-get install git -y
```

Comment: Technically your example is correct, can you try to execute manually on one of the machines and see if it works? Or using an ad-hoc command, also maybe you should try: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#parameter-force_apt_get

Comment: Very probably it's not Ansible's fault. Try from the command line. I guess there might be a difference among the configured sources(repos) or the git package has been put to hold ``apt-mark showhold``.

Comment: @ikora and @Vladimir Botka, I have updated the question. now `apt-mark showhold` returns nothing. In all five systems `/etc/apt/sources.list` files are identical.

Comment: Even `force_apt_get: yes` couldn't help.

Comment: `add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y` > this is not done in your playbook, so it makes sense that the tasks and command do not do the same. You should have a look at: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/apt_repository_module.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ansible executes the same code, across all the inventory hosts. You should start with what's different on `50.51.52.21`. It probably has a different repo that provides git.

Validate that with `grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | grep git` (on the working node), it will list all the installed repositories.

Add a task to validate the git repository *is installed on your ubuntu server.*

```
- apt_repository:
    repo: 'ppa:git-core/ppa'
    state: present
```

This should be set as the first task, then run the apt update and ultimately install git task.

Comment: Thanks β.εηοιτ.βε & Chen, Exactly i was missing `add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y` in playbook, after adding i am able to install successfully. Thanks a lot again.